# Pass event object to setter method in event callback

Tags: javascript, createjs, es6-class

I am working with createjs library.

I have the following class:

```
class Person {
 constructor(){
  this.name = 'John';
 }

 set updateName(event){
  this.name += event.key;
 }
}
```

Next, I instantiate the object like this:

```
var human = new Person();
```

I am trying to update the name of the person upon each keystroke like this:

```
window.addEventListener.on('keydown', human.updateName);
```

However, I get an error of "Cannot read property 'handleEvent' of undefined".

Comment: Can you share more  code before your listener?)

Comment: Are you expecting `set updateName(event){
  this.name += event.key;
 }` to work like `this.updateName = function(event){
  this.name += event.key;
 }` perhaps?

Comment: `window.addEventListener.on('keydown', ...)` seems quite odd, is that really how you hook up a keydown handler with CreateJS? Just looked at the source of a demo and it sure didn't look like that `.on` should be there...

Comment: `human.updateName` is a setter function. It is supposed be assigned with a new value, not called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`human.updateName` attempts to read the `updateName` property. Since you haven't defined a getter for it, the result of that is `undefined`. Apparently whatever you're passing it to (`window.addEventListener.on`) expects to be passed something other than `undefined`.

To pass the actual setter function is a bit tricky, you have to get access to it via `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` and then pass it in:

```
window.addEventListener.on('keydown', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(human, "updateName").set);
```

In order to ensure that the *right* person was updated, you'd probably need `bind` as well:

```
window.addEventListener.on('keydown', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(human, "updateName").set.bind(human));
```

Alternately, it would be rather simpler just to use an arrow function as glue:

```
window.addEventListener.on('keydown', e => {
    human.updateName = e;
});
```

---

Side note: `updateName` is the kind of name you'd give a **method**, not a property. Normally, a property would be called simply `name`.

Perhaps you intended it to be a method instead? If so:

```
class Person {
 constructor(){
  this.name = 'John';
 }

 updateName(event){ // No `set` on this line
  this.name += event.key;
 }
}
```

...and

```
window.addEventListener.on('keydown', human.updateName.bind(human));
```

or

```
window.addEventListener.on('keydown', e => {
    human.updateName(e);
});
```

Comment: Nice explanation!

Comment: Second part was exactly what I thought too